# Is post and pre increment as array index mentioned in Misra?

Tags: arrays, c, misra

Is the given example:

```
uint32_t i = 0U;
uint32_t arr[5U] = { 0U };
uint32_t b = arr[i++];
```

Anyhow not compliant with any Misra rules? Can one use pre increment and post increment inside of array indexing? Rule 12.1 is not clear to me about that.

Comment: This could be ambiguous to a nonzero number of reasonably well-trained readers and maintainers, so I'd separate it. I don't have any case studies to support this. This is off the cuff. `uint32_t b = arr[i]; i++;`

Comment: I would expect there's a rule that you can't do 2 things at the same time on one line.

Comment: @KamilCuk How about a line like `for (i = 0; i < 42; ++i) {` ?

Comment: `Rule 12.1 is not clear to me about that.` which MISRA version? From 2012, there are Rule 13.1 and 13.3 , that I believe you are close to braking.

Comment: Yes, 13.1 and 13.3 seem to be close but I still cannot tell.

Comment: Do you have a misra linter you can run it through and see if it barfs?

Comment: Still a good question. I hope people coming across this don't equate "closed" with "bad" and downvote. I'd like to see dependability and process questions on the hot-questions sidebar more often if I could.

Comment: It's not a great duplicate, my answer there was quite specific to that other question. If this is still unclear, let me know. Though please clarify if you are using MISRA C 2004 or 2012.